# Is there a way to automatically verify all imports in a Python script without running it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose that I have a somewhat long Python script (too long to hand-audit) that contains an expensive operation, followed by a bunch of library function calls that are dependent on the output of the expensive operation.

If I have not imported all the necessary modules for the library function calls, then Python will error out only *after* the expensive operation has finished, because Python interprets line by line.

Is there a way to automatically verify that I have all the necessary imports *without* either a) manually verifying it line by line or b) running through the expensive operation each time I miss a library?

Another way to put that question is whether there is a tool that will do what the C compiler does with respect to verifying dependencies before run time.

Comment: Create a fake version of the expensive operation that creates a dummy object, then run the later functions on that.

Comment: A fair idea, but unfortunately doesn't scale if I have multiple expensive operations that I'd need to create shims for.

Comment: [pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) it?

Comment: This is a static code analysis problem. As others have said, checkout pylint

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible, because dependencies can be injected at runtime.

Consider:

```
def foo(break_things):
    if not break_things:
        globals()['bar'] = lambda: None

long_result = ...
foo(long_result > 0)
bar()
```

Which depending on the runtime value of `long_result`, may give `NameError: name 'bar' is not defined`.

Comment: How about assuming only static dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

There is a module called [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/):

> Generate dependency graphs from Python code
>
> It uses the AST to parse
>   the Python files.
>
> This is very reliable, it always runs. **No module is
>   loaded.** Loading modules to figure out dependencies is almost always
>   problem, because a lot of codebases run initialization code in the
>   global namespace, which often requires additional setup. Snakefood is
>   guaranteed not to have this problem (it just runs, no matter what).

You can get a list of imports by calling `sfood-imports <script.py>`. Then you can import each module in the list one by one and see if it throws `ImportError`.

Or, just use [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/). Quote from docs:

> Error detection
>
> checking if declared interfaces are truly implemented
>
> checking if modules are imported

Hope that helps.